# How do I retain a file's name when converting to Base64?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using "Input" to get files in a react app. I'm able to get a blob using readAsDataURL() but it's stripping out the file name and is replacing with "Data". When I log the blob I'm getting "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAAS..." - "data" being the name that displays.

```
const handleGetFiles = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e);
    reader.onload = () => {
        fileCollection((fileCollection) => [...fileCollection, {id: index, data: reader.result}]);
    }
}
<Input 
  accept="image/*,video/*" 
  id="contained-button-file" 
  multiple type="file" 
  onChange={e => handleGetFiles(e)}
/>
```

[image]

Is there a way to use URL.createObjectURL(file) instead? I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

The filename that you're looking for doesn't come from the FileReader API, but rather from the input element's files property.

You can expose the file in 2 ways from React:

1. Through a ref:

```
const Input = () => {
  const inputEl = React.useRef();
  const handleGetFiles = () => {
    alert(inputEl.current.files[0].name)  
  };
  
  return (
    <input 
      ...
      onChange={handleGetFiles}
      ref={inputEl}
    />
  );
}
```

2. Through the event target

```
const Input = () => {
  const handleGetFiles = (e) => {
    alert(e.target.files[0].name)  
  };
  
  return (
    <input 
      ...
      onChange={handleGetFiles}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not have a problem getting the name. I'm having a problem retaining the name when I convert the file to base64 in order to upload the file to a server. As soon as I convert the file - as shown above - it displays "Data" as the file name. I don't know how to keep the name in the conversion.